# Return PDF Name When It Contains Certain Text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to look through a folder for a document and then return the name of that document.

I have code for returning existence.

```vb
Private Sub tester()
Dim FSO As Object, FolDir As Object, FileNm As Object, LastRow As Integer
Dim Flag As Boolean, WS As Worksheet, Cnt As Integer
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set FolDir = FSO.GetFolder("FILE PATH")
Set WS = Sheets("SHEET NAME")
With WS
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
For Cnt = 1 To LastRow
    Flag = False
    For Each FileNm In FolDir.Files
        If FileNm.Name Like "*" & ".pdf" Then
            If InStr(FileNm.Name, CStr(WS.Cells(Cnt, "A"))) Then
                WS.Cells(Cnt, "B") = "YES"
                Flag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next FileNm
    If Not Flag Then
        WS.Cells(Cnt, "B") = "NO"
    End If
Next Cnt
Set FolDir = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am trying to add optional arguments to then use a function to return the file name.

```vb
Private Function GetPdfName( _
  ByRef File As String, _
  Optional ByRef Flag As Variant) As String

    Dim FSO As Object, FolDir As Object, FileNm As Object, LastRow As Integer
    Dim Flag As Boolean, WS As Worksheet, Cnt As Integer
    Set FolDir = FSO.GetFolder("FILE PATH")
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Flag = False
    Set WS = Sheets("sheet4")
    For Each FileNm In FolDir.Files
        If FileNm.Name Like "*" & ".pdf" Then
            If InStr(FileNm.Name, CStr(WS.Cells(Cnt, "A"))) Then
            WS.Cells(Cnt, "B") = FileName
            Flag = True
            Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next FileNm
    If Not Flag Then
        WS.Cells(Cnt, "B") = "NO"
    End If
    Next Cnt
    Set FolDir = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
    
    FileName = FSO.GetFileName("FILE PATH")
End Function

Private Sub FSOGetFileName()
    GetPdfName( _
        With WS
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        For Cnt = 1 To LastRow)

End Sub
```

The Sub is returning an error on expected expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what optional parameter you need. Only 2 parameters are required, the folder to search and the target range for the results.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub tester()

    Const FILE_PATH = "c:\temp\"
    Const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"

    Dim FSO As Object, FolDir As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FolDir = FSO.GetFolder(FILE_PATH)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, lastrow As Long
    Set ws = Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    With ws
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 1 To lastrow
            Call GetPdfName(FolDir, .Cells(r, "A"))
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetPdfName(oFolder As Object, rng As Range)

    Dim oFile As Object, fname As String, s As String
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        fname = oFile.Name
        If fname Like "*.pdf" Then
            s = Left(fname, Len(fname) - 4) ' remove .pdf
            If InStr(1, s, CStr(rng), vbTextCompare) Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1) = oFile.Name
                rng.Offset(0, 2) = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = ""
    rng.Offset(0, 2) = False

End Function
```

for 2 criteria

```vb
Function GetPdfName2(oFolder As Object, rng As Range)

    Dim oFile As Object, fname As String, s As String
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        fname = oFile.Name
        If fname Like "*.pdf" Then
            s = Left(fname, Len(fname) - 4) ' remove .pdf
            If InStr(1, s, CStr(rng), vbTextCompare) or _
               InStr(1, s, CStr(rng.offset(0,1)), vbTextCompare) Then
                rng.Offset(0, 2) = oFile.Name
                rng.Offset(0, 3) = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rng.Offset(0, 2) = ""
    rng.Offset(0, 3) = False

End Function
```

Comment: so this worked great but now I'm kinda messing around with it to see if I can get it to search two separate variables. I added 
With ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & "B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 1 To lastrow
            Call GetPdfName(FolDir, .Cells(r, "B"))
        Next
    End With
and fixed the range on the "A" column and it does give me accurate results and works fine but I keep getting error 438 - object doesn't support this property or method. is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Alexis `With ws = Sheets("Sheet2")` should be `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")` then next line `With ws`. Why `.Range("A" & "B" & .Rows.Count)` , are the 2 columns A and B different lengths ? That code will find the last row in column AB.

Comment: they are the same length. how do I write it to have the range encompass both columns? and should the range in each "with" statement be the same? currently it works with the first with as range "A" and second range as "A" and "B" but not if both are "A" and "B" which based off what you said makes sense

Comment: @Alexis Ok, I think I understand - see update with added GetPdfName2 function.